# Summing does not work in longtabu

Tags: pdftex, longtable, expl3, latex3, longtabu

After getting to the solution with `longtable` I was finding I needed `longtabu` because I want to use `X` columns.

However, using `longtabu` the sum does break and shows double to correct value.
And when using a `X`column it adds even more to it.

Is that because the table is compiled multiple times and therefore also running the adding part multiple times? Is there another way to solve this with `expl3` or do I just need to use `longtable` and then manually calculate the `X` column instead to make the table fill the whole `textwidth`?

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{opensans}

\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newtime}{m}
{
    \fp_new:c { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp }
}
\newtime{default} % initialize one

\NewDocumentCommand{\resettime}{O{default}}{
    \fp_gset:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { \fpeval{0} }
}

% \addtime* will also show the added time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{sO{default}mm}
{
    \timecalc_time_add:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }

    % with \addtime* also show what's been added    
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{default}m}
{
    \timecalc_time_str:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}

\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_days_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_hours_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_add:nnn
{
    \str_case:nnF { #3 }
    {
        {h}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 } }
        {d}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 * 24 } }
        {min}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 } }
    }
    {\ERROR}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \int_div_mod:nnn {
    \int_set:Nn #3 
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    
    \int_set:Nn #1
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_str:nn
{
    % round to an integral number of minutes
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
        { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:c { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp }, 0 ) } }

    \bool_if:nTF
    {
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{d}
    }
    {%yes
        % compute and remove the number of days
        \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{1440}{\l__timecalc_time_days_int}
        
        % now print the days
        \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_days_int > 0 }
        { \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_days_int }\,\textup{d}\; }
        {% no days
            \unkern
        }
    }{} % no

    \bool_if:nTF
    {
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{h} ||
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{d} 
    }
    {%yes
        % compute and remove the number of hours
        \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{60}{\l__timecalc_time_hours_int}
        
        % now print the hours
        \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int > 0 }
        {
            \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int }\,\textup{h}\;
        }
        {% no hours
            \unkern
        }       
    }{} % no


    % now print the minutes
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int }\,\textup{min}
    }
    {% no minutes
        0\,min%\unkern
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]
\usepackage{tabu}%

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{longtable}{r}
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \addtime*{30}{min}\\
        \addtime*{4}{h}  \\
    \end{longtable}
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime{h}.

    \resettime
    Current time: \strtime{h}.
    
    \begin{longtabu}{r}%
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \addtime*{30}{min}\\
        \addtime*{4}{h}  \\
    \end{longtabu}%

    This leads to a complete time of \strtime{h}.   

    \resettime
    Current time: \strtime{h}.
    
    \begin{longtabu}{X}%
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \addtime*{30}{min}\\
        \addtime*{4}{h}  \\ 
    \end{longtabu}%
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime{h}.
            
\end{document}
```

Comment: tabu does not work at all, and is unmaintained

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have heard that. However it leads to very good results with long tables... Do you have an adequate replacement for that? I only want multi-page tables that easily span the whole `textwidth` (usually with on `X` column) and work with counters...

Comment: See `tabularray` package. It is LaTeX3based package,   quite similar to `tabu`.  Recent version (2023A) has added library `functional` which provide what you after (if I correctly understood your question)

Comment: There's also the [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) package and its eponymous environment, which combines the capabilities of the `longtable` and `tabularx` environments.

Comment: What's the target width of your table?

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks. I had had  a look at both before but felt very discouraged to use it since the examples provided in the documentation did not even work...

Comment: @Mico: Always `\textwidth`.

Comment: tabu is broken. So don't use it. You won't get any support for it. See the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu . And personally I quite rarely need X columns. In most cases one can simply calculate the needed width.

Comment: @mrCarnivore, sorry? Which example from documentation not work? My findings are opposite.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Can you give me a hint how to easily calulate the needed width? The other columns are dependent on the content and therefore you would need to know the maximum width of them to calculate the X column width which is quite hard in most cases...

Comment: @Zarko: I am trying to compile the code on page 38 of this: https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf. I have encapsulated it in `\begin{document} .. \end{document}` and of course used `\usepackage{tabularray}`. However, I get `misplaced \noalign`, `You can't use\hrule here`, `Missing number, treated as zero`  and other errors when running the code...

Comment: @Zarko: Having being able to run the example after some pointers I still do not like it as much as `longtabu` since it shows only english text in "Continued" (even with `babe`l set to `ngerman`) and I seem not to be able to remove the "table 1"...  And worse: It still leads to the sum to being too high...

Comment: longtable writes the width of the columns into the aux-file. So you can retrieve them on a second calculation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: how do I retrieve the column widths from the .aux-file and then use it in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### edited to unify coding style and use OP's initial code

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{opensans}

\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}



% \newcommand\tabudoonlyatlast{%
%  \ifx\tabu@savecounters\relax\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
% }

\ExplSyntaxOn

% WARNING! THIS USES \tex_relax:D WHICH IS FORBIDDEN (D = DoNotUse)
% But I have no idea what should take its place.
% Not "\relax"? that would be way too lenient. 
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mrCarnivoreprotect}{m}{
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF { \tabu@savecounters } { \tex_relax:D }
                   { }
                   { #1 }
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand{\newtime}{m}
{
    \fp_new:c { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp }
}
\newtime{default} % initialize one

\NewDocumentCommand{\resettime}{O{default}}{
    \fp_gset:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { \fpeval{0} }
}

% \addtime* will also show the added time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{sO{default}mm}
{
    \timecalc_time_add:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }

    % with \addtime* also show what's been added    
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{default}m}
{
    \timecalc_time_str:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}

\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_days_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_hours_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_add:nnn
{
    \str_case:nnF { #3 }
    {
        {h}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 } }
        {d}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 * 24 } }
        {min}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 } }
    }
    {\ERROR}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \int_div_mod:nnn {
    \int_set:Nn #3 
        { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    
    \int_set:Nn #1
        { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_str:nn
{
    % round to an integral number of minutes
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
        { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:c { g_timecalc_time_#1_fp }, 0 ) } }

    \bool_if:nTF
    {
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{d}
    }
    {%yes
        % compute and remove the number of days
        \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{1440}{\l__timecalc_time_days_int}
        
        % now print the days
        \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_days_int > 0 }
        { \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_days_int }\,\textup{d}\; }
        {% no days
            \unkern
        }
    }{} % no

    \bool_if:nTF
    {
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{h} ||
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{d} 
    }
    {%yes
        % compute and remove the number of hours
        \int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{60}{\l__timecalc_time_hours_int}
        
        % now print the hours
        \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int > 0 }
        {
            \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int }\,\textup{h}\;
        }
        {% no hours
            \unkern
        }       
    }{} % no


    % now print the minutes
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int }\,\textup{min}
    }
    {% no minutes
        0\,min%\unkern
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]
\usepackage{tabu}%

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{longtable}{r}
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \addtime*{30}{min}\\
        \addtime*{4}{h}\\
    \end{longtable}
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime{h}.

    \resettime
    Current time: \strtime{h}.
    
    \begin{longtabu}{r}%
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \mrCarnivoreprotect{\addtime*{30}{min}}\\
        \mrCarnivoreprotect{\addtime*{4}{h}}\\
    \end{longtabu}%

    This leads to a complete time of \strtime{h}.   

    \resettime
    Current time: \strtime{h}.
    
    \begin{longtabu}{X}%
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        \mrCarnivoreprotect{\addtime*{30}{min}}\\
        \mrCarnivoreprotect{\addtime*{4}{h}}\\ 
    \end{longtabu}%
    
    This leads to a complete time of \strtime{h}.
            
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: tabu output with LaTeX3]

#### original version

tabu does multiple passes (or may do), perhaps 2 or 3 even more perhaps (not sure).  I looked quickly at its code but did not find a conditional one can query.  However it looks as if the `\tabu@savecounters` is set to `\relax` after having being used during tabu preliminary and is reset for final pass (probably from exiting a group).  Hence this.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultsans, scale=0.9]{opensans}

\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]
\usepackage{tabu}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\tabudoonlyatlast{%
 \ifx\tabu@savecounters\relax\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\def\x{0}
\def\stepx{\xdef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1}}

Value of x: \x.

    \begin{longtabu}{r}%
        \textbf{time}
        \endhead
        initial x = \x\\
        final x = \tabudoonlyatlast{\stepx}\x
    \end{longtabu}

Value of x: \x.
\end{document}
```

[image: tabu output]

This being said, we are thus modifying the output at the final typesetting pass and it is possible that we mess up tabu meaurements (say when we go from 9 to 10).  So it should be used with the variable thing rendered in fixed-width box, to be sure.

Comment: Thank you! That really works like a charm! Since these kinds of commands I do not really understand, yet and I am trying to learn latex3, can you also give me a latex3 version of that so I can keep consistency in the code?

Comment: @mrCarnivore glad it helped. You mean the command `\tabudoonlyatlast`? ok... give me a few hours to read interface3.pdf and I will provide it in latex3, only be patient please.  Btw I thought I should have named it `\tabudelaytolast` or `\tabuprotect`. Or rather `\mrcarnivoreprotect`! ;-)

Comment: @mrCarnivore I have done the edit; sorry if you witnessed somewhat erratic edits, but I initially forgot to update the document body to actually use `\mrCarnivoreprotect`.... but now all should have stabilized... I have a big doubt about my usage of `tex_relax:D` which I understand is not correct.  But what use then? Perhaps some gentle LaTeXian will edit and correct my post...

Comment: I'm not an expert but according to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99435/is-there-a-latex3-approach-to-ignorespaces it seems that a valid replacement for `\tex_relax:D` would be `\scan_stop:`. Why is `\relax` not sufficient? And why are you checking whether `\tabu@savecounters` is equal to `\tex_relax:D` anyways?

Comment: `\relax` like all other TeX primitive control sequences such as `\box` is destined, theoretically, around 2100 take or add a few decades to be made undefined.  It will exist course internally to LaTeX3 under another name.  Thanks for pointing out ``\scan_stop:``.  But  is not something which sounds like being quaranteed to be for all eternity `\relax` (it could perhaps be made equivalent to some weird thing which acts like `\relax` but isn't equivalent in an `\ifx` test, as end user how  I can not know what will happen in future?). (to be cont.)

Comment: (cont.) I did not use `\relax` because I wanted to act as a student of LaTeX3. I did not look too much (I will now a bit more) but did not find an official document level equivalent.  You solved that by pointing ``\scan_stop:``, but I explained why I would then prefer not to use it.  However I do feel that you should replace my good-will `\tex_relax:D` by `\relax`... as long as your document will be using tabu, the grand plan of LaTeX3 of making **all** TeX primitives undefined is bound to break your documents around 2100 anyhow...

Comment: there is no mention of `\relax` in `expl3.pdf` and only 3 hits in `interface3.pdf` none of which mentions `\scan_stop:` is `\relax`. The official documentation of `\scan_stop:` is *A non-expandable function which does nothing. Does not vanish on expansion but pro- duces no typeset output.* How can I conclude from this that it will for all eternity be the `\relax` TeX primitive?

Comment: Thanks for the `expl3` version! It works. Still I have not understood what `\scan_stop:` or `\relax` really do. It seems to be a good version to use `\relax` for now. Thanks again for your efforts!

Comment: @mrCarnivore examination of the code of `tabu` and some brief experiment led me to conclusion that `\tabu@savecounters` is set to `\relax` after having done its job at start of first pass (before cells actually execute) and is reset to a specific definition at last pass.  So the macro is testing whether the `\meaning` of `\tabu@savecounters` is `\relax` and if it is it removes the argument from expanding.

Answer (score 2):

to answer the question in the comments: `longtable` stores the width of columns for every table in the aux file in a command (which uses a roman number):

```
\gdef \LT@i {\LT@entry 
    {1}{17.00003pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{27.27783pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{32.55562pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{50.88902pt}}
\gdef \LT@ii {\LT@entry 
    {1}{59.45284pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{91.35826pt}\LT@entry 
    {1}{80.13902pt}}
```

You can retrieve the columns size by processing this command, e.g. before the longtable. It is up to you what you do with the info. Here I only show it and draw rules (be aware that info is only there at the second compilation, so you need some test and fall back for the first).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tikz}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand\shownextlongtablewidth
 {
  \group_begin:
  \int_zero:N\l_tmpa_int
  \tl_if_exist:cT {LT@\int_to_roman:n{\c@LT@tables+1}}
   {
    \par\centering % to center the rules like the longtable
    \cs_set:Npn \LT@entry##1##2
     {
      \int_incr:N\l_tmpa_int
      \typeout{Width~of~column~\int_use:N\l_tmpa_int\c_space_tl~
               in~table~\int_eval:n{\c@LT@tables+1}~is~##2}
      \tikz{\draw[red,<->](0,0)--++(##2,0)}         
     } 
    \tl_use:c{LT@\int_to_roman:n{\c@LT@tables+1}}%
    \par
   }
  \group_end:
 }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\shownextlongtablewidth 
\begin{longtable}{lcl|l}
a&abc & duck & blubblub
\end{longtable}

\shownextlongtablewidth
\begin{longtable}{l@{\hspace{1cm}}p{3cm}l}
12345&abc & some long word \\
b & xxxxxxx &123
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The log-file will then say

```
Width of column 1 in table 1 is 17.00003pt
Width of column 2 in table 1 is 27.27783pt
Width of column 3 in table 1 is 32.55562pt
Width of column 4 in table 1 is 50.88902pt
Width of column 1 in table 2 is 59.45284pt
Width of column 2 in table 2 is 91.35826pt
Width of column 3 in table 2 is 80.13902pt
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is very advanced and I would not know how to use that code to adapt the column widths. However, thank you very much for giving me a piece of code to try to understand and play around with as a starting point!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you employ the [xltabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular) package and use the following code.

- in the preamble:

  ```
  \usepackage{xltabular}
  \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
  ```
- in the body of the document:

  ```
  \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{R}
      \textbf{time}
      \endhead
      \addtime*{30}{min}\\
      \addtime*{4}{h} n \\
  \end{xltabular}
  ```

  where `\addtime` is one of the L3-syntax commands defined in the query you posted.

I can't help but remark that if the table really contains just three rows, the machinery of `longtable` and/or `xltabular` packages isn't exactly well-deployed here.

Comment: Thanks for the example. For the MWE I created a table with only limited lines. Your solution suffers from the same problems as `longtabu`: the sum is also more than double the expected amount. So it is not a solution...

Comment: @mrCarnivore - Sorry, I evidently misunderstood the objective of your query. I thought it was about how to set up a table that takes a target width as one of its inputs.